# Drag/Drop Robot Class

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

I would like to drag and drop using the Robot class in Java. For some reason the code below isn't working. Is there an alternative to this method?

```
    public static void main (String args []){
    Robot robot = new Robot ();

    robot.mouseMove(350, 226);
    robot.keyPress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseMove(250, 350);
    robot.keyRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

}

Comment: How far apart are those two x,y points? - if they are too close together, the system may not register a drag event.

Comment: The new position is approximately 25px away. Sorry I included some irrelevant objects. I have now edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `mousePress()` and `mouseRelease()`, not `keyPress()` and `keyRelease()`

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe I overlooked that. What a stupid mistake. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is helps anyone and you:

```
public static void click(int x , int y,int x2, int y2) throws AWTException, InterruptedException{
    Robot b11 = new Robot();

    b11.mouseMove(x, y);    
    b11.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    Thread.sleep(1000);//There is pause in miliseconds
    b11.mouseMove(x2, y2);
    b11.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

}
```